# How to manage WiFi connection in universal app (win 8.1)?

Tags: c#

I'm writing universal app for win 8.1 using C#, which should have capability to show available WiFi networks and manage connecting to them.

I've found libraries for that: http://managedwifi.codeplex.com/ or http://blogs.msdn.com/b/winsdk/archive/2015/01/09/wlan-programming-how-to-tips-and-tricks-including-using-it-in-c.aspx .
Unfortunately they are not build for .NETCore and I haven't find a way to include it and compile them in my project.

I've tried also Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation.GetConnectionProfiles but I can get names but not the exact SSID displayed to the user.

Comment: You are mentioning .NETCore and 8.1, which platform are you targeting? 8.1 does not use .NetCore.

Comment: I'm targeting Win 8.1 and Windows Phone 8, that's why I've chosen "Universal Windows 8.1"

Comment: 8.1 and 8 are not using .NETCore.

Comment: Well, I don't know but when I'm trying adding reference to one dll library mentioned in links, I'm getting "A reference to 'path_to_dll' could not be added. The project targets '.NETCore' while the file reference targets '.NETFramework'. This is not a supported scenario"
I'm using VS Community 2015

Comment: Are you sure your project does not target UWP (Windows Universal APP)?

Comment: It DOES target UWP, as mentioned in title, I've added "_(win 8.1)_" only to differentiate between universal for win 10 and universal for windows 8. Maybe it was not clear from my side, I don't know differences between universal 10/8.1 and a proper way to differentiate them properly. In VS studio I have two options: _Universal Windows_ and _Universal Windows 8.1_. I've chosen latter one.

Comment: But I am speaking about the "Windows Universal App", which is Windows 10 only.

Comment: OK, I've used that exact template -> https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=D6043DFDFF31FC9C!72847&authkey=!APo7w1XiHamIaAg&v=3&ithint=photo%2cpng . It does says .NET Framework 4.5.2 and I have no idea why it gives error about .NETCore.